# Simple HashMap remove function doesn't update the map entries

Tags: java, algorithm, hashmap

I'm trying to implement a simple hash map in which each entry of the map is represented as a `Node` single linked list, and I have an array of entries such as `Node[] nodes`:

```java
static final class Node {
        int key;
        int value;
        Node next;
        int hash;

        Node(int key, int value, Node next, int hash) {
            this.key = key;
            this.value = value;
            this.next = next;
            this.hash = hash;
        }
}
```

Here is the remove method, which first tries to locate the index position of the key in the HashMap, and then scans linearly each node in this entry and removes the matched key in the map:

```java
public void remove(int key) {
        int hash = computeHash(key);
        Node node = nodes[hash];
        if (node == null) {
            return;
        }

        Node prev = null;
        while (node.key != key && node.next != null) {
            prev = node;
            node = node.next;
        }
        if (node.key == key) {
            if (prev != null) {
                prev.next = node.next;
            } else if (prev == null) {
                node = node.next;
            } else {
                node = null;
            }
            size--;
        }
}
```

It doesn't make the matched node removed from the `nodes` outside and only the local variable referenced is affected. Since I have a reference to the node I want to remove it from the `nodes` (in case there is a matched key), having its address and trying to deference it to `null`, but it's invalid. I'm glad to hear some explanation why this code doesn't work.

I have a simple test like this:

```java
MyHashMap map = new MyHashMap();
map.put(1, 1);
map.put(2, 1);
map.remove(1);
System.out.println(map.get(1)); // still returns 1
```

Comment: Can you provide all the code required to reproduce this problem, including a test? Thank you.

Comment: You're creating a new data structure, calling it a
[hash map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table), but instead of O(1) complexity for remove it has 
O(n) compexity since it has to iterate all nodes until a match is found?

Comment: This is basically how a HashMap in Java is implemented, each entry is represented as a linked list in case of collision. And yeah, the worst case for removal would be O(n).

Comment: I missed that you’re using an array of Node. So if the linked list is _only_ for key collisions, then this makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

You local variable `node` is a **copy** of `nodes[hash]`. Assigning to a copy doesn't change the original. You need to change your code so that it updates the original. And you don't need to check whether `node.next` equals `null`: it doesn't matter, if it's `null` you will assign `null` and that's precisely what you want.

```
if (node.key == key) {
    if (prev != null) {
        prev.next = node.next;
    } else {
        nodes[hash] = node.next;
    }
    size--;
}
```

Comment: Can you explain why the copy of this node doesn't refer to the original one, I thought they would point to the same memory address?

Comment: Yes, you have two copies of an object reference that both point to the same memory address. But you're not changing anything at the memory address. You're changing the reference. And the reference is a copy.

Answer (score -1):

It's wrong to check node.next not equals null. You shouldn't care the next element, The next element from the removed one will never be referred.
The source code from HashMap is:

```
if (node == p)
   tab[index] = node.next;
else
   p.next = node.next;
++modCount;
--size;
```

The 'p' is approach to your 'prev'.The HashMap assign the value to the first element in this hash earlier.